Unable to build ROS package
I've been trying to compile this project using the steps in the documentation and ran into the following issue when running colcon build --symlink-install. Yes, I am aware that it is not an up to date version but platform I'm running this only supports ROS Foxy. the Thanks for any help.
colcon build --symlink-install
Starting >>> isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces
[Processing: isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces]                              
Finished <<< isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces [30.3s]                    
Starting >>> isaac_ros_apriltag
--- stderr: isaac_ros_apriltag                           
CMake Error at /home/admin/your_ws/src/install/isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces/share/isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces/cmake/ament_cmake_export_targets-extras.cmake:18 (message):
  Failed to find exported target names in
  '/home/admin/your_ws/src/install/isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces/share/isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces/cmake/isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces__rosidl_generator_cExport.cmake'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/admin/your_ws/src/install/isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces/share/isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces/cmake/isaac_ros_apriltag_interfacesConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /opt/ros/foxy/install/share/ament_cmake_auto/cmake/ament_auto_find_build_dependencies.cmake:67 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (ament_auto_find_build_dependencies)


You need to install the dependencies of this package on your ros2 workspace:
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y

Then rebuild the pkg:
colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select isaac_ros_apriltag_interfaces

Then build the next one:
colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select isaac_ros_apriltag

If it doesn't work you need to check what is missing in your. From your log it seems that is missing some build dependencies.
Did you install on your system all these ones provided by your link?

